# Laravel - softDelete set null relationship

Tags: laravel

Is there a way to set the child relation foreign key to null when you soft delete the parent? I'll show an example below.

```
User
id | name | country | deleted_at
1    James  USA       2020-02-07 11:20:50

Profile
id | user_id | profession
1    1        Chef
```

The `user_id` still remains despite being soft deleted, thus I'm having a hard time setting if conditions when a column value should be null. I don't know if this is a bug with Laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite User model's `boot` method, when you soft-delete on User, set the `user_id` to be nullable:

```php
protected static function boot() {
    parent::boot();

    static::deleting(function($user) {
        $user->profile()->update(['user_id' => null]);
    });
}
```